# Alignment issue when trying to fix the design android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

How to make the alignment to properly fit exactly to the above heading?

You can see the below screenshot where it's mismatching. Moreover even the box too moving when text in profile icon gets increased.

Here is my code. [main.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAlabaster">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Retailer"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Hari sebelumnya"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="Pindahkan ke hari"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_very_small" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
   </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

in table row.xml:

***I couldn't adjust this row to fit exactly equal to the above layout which has headers and also the position too in table row***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">


            <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="14234234"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/route_plan_default_name"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/from_day"
                    android:layout_width="86dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Selasa"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/right_arrow"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/to_day"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/dropdown"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Kamis"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My output:

[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: Use `weightsum` for main LinearLayout

Comment: can you please correct me where i need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Change your **table row.xml:** code like below.

I just add **android:layout_weight** attribute and divide this **weight** into **child layouts** and remove some **margin padding** attributes.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:weightSum=".3">


        <com.hutchison.h3i.newangie.customviews.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/growth_sell_in_out_icon_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="14234234"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_txt_acc_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/route_plan_default_name"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".3">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/from_day"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Selasa"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum=".1"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/right_arrow"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:weightSum=".3">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/to_day"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_grey_curve"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/dropdown"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Kamis"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

it's not a complete implementation its just an idea how you can achieve your requirement and don't use the **hardcoded values** for **views** height, width, and margin, padding its bad habit and not make a responsive view means your **UI** isn't  displaying perfectly on all **Android devices.**

Comment: Need more help just ping me.

Comment: Hello Hassan, I replaced the layouts with weight by following this. But the design is still mismatching with headers.

Comment: try to understand the logic means how to use the layout_weight than you can easily match your design

Comment: Did you replace android:layout_width="wrap_content" by android:layout_width="0dp" ? Maybe copy/paste Hassan solution, and edit after would be better